# Android notification navigate to existing activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm tinkering with Android notifications. I have a single Activity app with Fragment navigation, and this is what I'm trying to achieve: when I click on a notification, I want to

- start a new instance of my Activity if there is none
- if there is one in the back stack or another task, reopen that **in the fragment I left it in**

What I'm currently doing:

```
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        return TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
            getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
```

I tried every `launchMode` in the manifest for my Activity, but it always starts from the first activity screen and not the one I left the app in.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1) Never ever use `TaskStackBuilder`. The default behaviour is to reset the task (ie: remove any existing activities in the stack), which is usually not what you want. `TaskStackBuilder` can be used to build complex back stacks, but you really need to understand how it works under the covers and it has a lot of side-effects. Generally speaking, avoid it if you can.

Rule #2) If you just want to bring an existing task to the foreground, in whatever state it was in when you left it, use a "launch `Intent`" from the `PackageManager`:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager()
    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name.of.app.to.launch");
startActivity(intent);
```

and you don't need any special flags or launch modes.

Rule #3) Avoid using the special launch modes `singleTask` and `singleInstance`. They generally aren't what you need and they have a lot of side-effects that are not obvious. You usually only need these if you are building a HOME-screen replacement.